# flask - how to send data and get it back

Tags: python, session, web, caching, flask

i am developing a little app in flask and i need to let the user to answer 20 shuffled questions one by one.
i have a list of question and i want to send one question to the html each time the user push "next" button.

```
    @app.route('/handleQuestions', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def handleQuestions():
        #first time - first question
        if not request.method == 'POST':
            try:
                pdQuestions = GetShuffeledQuestions()
                session['pdQuestions'] = pdQuestions
                i=0
                session['qindex']=i
                questionTosend = session.get('pdQuestions').iloc[[i]]['question'].item()
                print(questionTosend)
                return  render_template('questionsTemplate.html',progress=round((i/24)*100), sent=questionTosend)
            except Exception as ex:
                print(ex)
        else:
            answer = request.form.to_dict(flat=False)       
            print(answer)
            #next question
            i=session['qindex']+1
            session['qindex']=i
            questionTosend = session.get('pdQuestions').iloc[[i]]['question'].item()
            print(questionTosend)
            return  render_template('questionsTemplate.html',progress=round((i/24)*100), sent=questionTosend)
            print('done')
```

where can i keep the list?
and how can iterate it to the page?
i want the user to get 1 question each time, i will save the answer and give him the next question.

i have tried to save it on the session, but the list is too big and it crash when i save it to the session.

Comment: sounds like you need a database

Comment: :\ this what i try to avoid...

Comment: why are you trying to avoid the proper way to do something?

Comment: i guess you right. but is there any way to pass the list to view and get it back in the post?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? There is no need to keep sending the list to the front end and back again just to display one item from the list each time. As suggested, you could back this up with a really simple SQLite database. If you _really_ wanted to keep it all in a session, you'll need to use something like flask-session which will not be so limited in size

Comment: it crashed with flask-session and also with flask-kvsesseion... so DB it is.. thanx